# Expectation in java fall down when i put letter a b c

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have a problem my teacher want in code expectation and try catch. Protecting before wrong input and I need put this to my code I have something but isn't work properly if I put some letter like a,b,c the program fall down.

```
package projectprucha;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Projectprucha {

public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int Choose;

    do {

        writeMenu();
        Choose = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        try {
            switch (Choose) {

                case 1:

                    Joke vtip = new Joke();
                    vtip.Napis();
                    JokeII vtipII = new JokeII();
                    vtipII.NapisII();
                    break;

                case 2:

                    Kalkulacka.staticMethod();
                    break;

                case 3:

                    Moudro rada = new Moudro();
                    rada.Rekni();

                case 0:
                    System.out.println("You have exited the system");
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in the data you have entered please try again");

        }
    } while (Choose != 0);

}

  private static void writeMenu() {
    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("1: Něco pro zasmání");
    System.out.println("2: Kalkulačka");
    System.out.println("3: Rada do života");
    System.out.println("0: Ukončit program");
}

}
```

Comment: you can get the input as a string (`scan.next()`), check if it is a number (for example with a regular expression) and then convert it to a number

Comment: the exception will be thrown by `scan.nextInt()` so you should move this line (and the following) into the `try` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error by a non-numerical input is that `nextInt` is not in your `try` block. The registered problems at the other answers leads me to this solution. You need to get the complete line as input and parse it to an `int`. Now you additionally need to catch a `NumberFormatException`:

```
do {
    try {
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        int choose = Integer.parseInt(input);
        // ...
    catch (InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in the data you have entered please try again");
    }
} while (true);
```

You don't need `choose` outside your loop because you're using `System.exit(0)` if input is 0.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I guess it's the best solution in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Put try before taking the input so that if there is exception in input type your error will be caught in catch.

```
package projectprucha;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Projectprucha {


public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

int Choose;

do {

    writeMenu();
try{
    Choose = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();


        switch (Choose) {

            case 1:

                Joke vtip = new Joke();
                vtip.Napis();
                JokeII vtipII = new JokeII();
                vtipII.NapisII();
                break;

            case 2:

                Kalkulacka.staticMethod();
                break;

            case 3:

                Moudro rada = new Moudro();
                rada.Rekni();

            case 0:
                System.out.println("You have exited the system");
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                throw new InputMismatchException();
        }
}
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in the data you have entered please 
try again");

    }
} while (Choose != 0);

}

 private static void writeMenu() {
System.out.println("Menu");
System.out.println("1: Něco pro zasmání");
System.out.println("2: Kalkulačka");
System.out.println("3: Rada do života");
System.out.println("0: Ukončit program");
}

}
```

Comment: That answer is worse than the first one... This won't compile because your `try` is in class body

Answer (score -2):

You have your datatype integer for choose variable. So you cannot pass character or String as switch parameter.

Thanks

Comment: The question is not why the error occurs but how to catch it.

Comment: Yes I agree but it is most important to know why he is getting error for input like a,b,c. So we can go for solution. Please check posted solution. cheers